# Google Custom Search API: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup

Tags: java, api, google-custom-search

The Google Custom Search API is denying my requests, saying I've exceeded the limit. Their limit is 100 requests/day but I've not made any successful requests yet, and I've only made a total of about 5 requests.

I'm creating a Java application to use the Google CustomSearch API to make searches using my CustomSearch API key.

```
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.Customsearch;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.model.Result;    

public class SearchBuilder {
public SearchBuilder() {
            search = new Customsearch.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null)               .setApplicationName("MyApp").build();
    }

    public List<Result> search(String query) throws IOException {         
        return search(query,100);
    }
}
```

I've tried refreshing the API key, ensuring its enabled on the API Console but still no luck.

Running this code with my API key results in the following exception:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "reason" : "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
  } ],
  "message" : "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
}
```

**But** I don't think code is the problem, as both a normal GET request and the Java code return the same JSON message citing exceeding my limit.

It says continued use requires signup but I'm unsure what this means - I've already signed up for an API key.

Answer (score 2):

The problem **was** my Java code, I think I wasn't adding the credentials correctly in my code. Turns out I was malforming my GET request too.

Running the edited Google example returns the expected JSON search results:

```
curl -l GET 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures'
```

Answer (score -1):

A request doesn't have to be 'succesful' to be counted to the limit. In googles eyes it is 'succesful' since it was a request. You are just not handling the data correctly. Signing up probably refers to the fact that you have to put in some bank details so that they can charge you for all the next requests.

As for the problem you yourself are having, I can't really help without some more code.

Comment: Hi Luca, sorry if I made it unclear before. I've just edited my question to include that I've only made around 5 requests - certainly not over the limit. But I will look into adding billing information in case this might still be an issue.